# What does the ?? mean in a registry value?

Tags: registry, key

I am trying to figure out a BSOD problem on my PC and I need to understand what "??" means in a registry value (e.g. **\??\C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\vmm.sys**)? I have the issue narrowed down to just a few files but I cannot understand this "**??**" notation. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's the *kernel*'s naming style. `\??` is (almost) a synonym for `\DosDevices`, which is where all Win32 objects/symbolic links are located by default.

Basically, `kernel32.dll` is the "Win32 subsystem", which implements (or rather, wraps) a lot of the functionality of Windows. The naming scheme it uses is the one you see everywhere, like `C:\Windows`.

But that's **not** how the kernel sees the system! Like Unix, which has an object hierarchy rooted at `/`, Windows also has a hierarchy, rooted at `\`, whose APIs you can access by calling the functions in `ntdll.dll` (which would bypass `kernel32.dll`). So what you really see in Win32 is a *subset* of what's actually there -- namely, the name `C:` actually maps to `\??\C:` in the kernel.

Download [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657) to see what I mean. (See the `GLOBAL??` key.)

Useful readings:

[The kernel object namespace and Win32, part 1](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=61)
[The kernel object namespace and Win32, part 2](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=86)
[The kernel object namespace and Win32, part 3](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=92)

Comment: Amazingly fast answer! Thanks! I will read through these links. This should be very useful! I have a conflict between our real-time kernel and ntoskrnl.exe, where I get a BSOD when I enable the service. This is for a software that my company produces but this is a new version for x64 O/S.